# Create random users on SQL Server 2019 with Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I would like to know if there's a way to create an user with python on a SQL Server 2019? Because I succeed to connect and create a database on the server but I can't connected to the database then...

Here's a bit of my code.

```
def create_user(self):
    global date
    utilisateur = self.nom_utilisateur.get()
    password = self.password.get()
    dbname = utilisateur + str(date.year)
    mydb = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', host='DELL-G3\SQLEXPRESS', iud=utilisateur, psw=password)
    mydb.autocommit = True
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s" % dbname)

    try:
        mkuser = utilisateur
        mkpass = password
        creation = "CREATE USER '%s'@'DELL-G3\SQLEXPRESS' IDENTIFIED BY '%s' FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER" % (mkuser, mkpass)
        cursor.execute(creation)

        grant = "GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON *.* TO '%s'@'DELL-G3\SQLEXPRESS'" % (mkuser)
        cursor.execute(grant)

    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        print('error')

    mydb.close()
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use Oracle syntax on Microsoft SQL Server. On SQL Server there are two levels of access: Logins, created by [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql), have access at the server level and may be Windows Authenticated or SQL Authenticated (username/password); Users, created by [CREATE USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql), have access within a single database. Logins get mapped to Users in particular database/s.

Comment: I found a solution ! Thanks for answering !! :)